# Expanding list refs in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a list in Perl, and I'm trying to "expand" any lists it contains.

For example:

```
my @l = (
  'foo',
  ['A', 'B'],
  'bar',
  ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
  'baz',
);
```

I'd like to expand the lists to get this:

```
my @want = (
  [qw/ foo A bar X baz /],
  [qw/ foo A bar Y baz /],
  [qw/ foo A bar Z baz /],
  [qw/ foo B bar X baz /],
  [qw/ foo B bar Y baz /],
  [qw/ foo B bar Z baz /],
);
```

I came up with this, which works, but is ugly and doesn't result in sensibly ordered array:

```
my @out = ([]);
foreach my $elt (@l){
    if( ref($elt) eq 'ARRAY' ){
        my $n = scalar(@$elt);
        my @_out;
        # expand 
        for( my $i=0; $i<$n; $i++ ){
            foreach my $o (@out){
                push(@_out, [@$o]);
            }
        }
        for( my $i=0; $i<@_out; $i++ ){
            push(@{$_out[$i]}, $elt->[$i % $n]);
        }
        @out = @_out;
    }
    else{
        foreach my $o (@out){
            push(@$o, $elt);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to accomplish this operation?

Comment: You're looking for the Cartesian product. There are several modules out there to do this, but I personally like [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct). It takes an arrayref of arrayrefs, but it would be easy to modify your input array.

Comment: You don't have a list, you have an array. You aren't trying to expand lists, you are trying to expand arrays. In Perl, [lists and arrays are different things](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compute the Cartesian product of the elements in your array. You can use [`Math::Cartesian::Product`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Cartesian::Product) from CPAN to do this:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use Math::Cartesian::Product;
cartesian { print "@_","\n"; } 
   ([qw(foo)], [qw(A B)], [qw(bar)], [qw(X Y Z)], [qw(baz)]);

# outputs
# foo A bar X baz
# foo A bar Y baz
# foo A bar Z baz
# foo B bar X baz
# foo B bar Y baz
# foo B bar Z baz
```

Note, this does require you to place each of your input elements in an arrayref and if you want an array of arrayrefs as your output (from your example) you will need to encode that logic in the block.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I thought I'd add another possible solution

The module [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct) will also get the result wanted. (The input array elements must all be array references.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;
use Set::CrossProduct;

my @l = (
  'foo',
  ['A', 'B'],
  'bar',
  ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
  'baz',
);

# all elements of array must be array refs
@l = map ref eq 'ARRAY' ? $_ : [$_], @l;

my @wanted = Set::CrossProduct->new(\@l)->combinations;

dd \@wanted;
```

The data dump output was

```
[
  ["foo", "A", "bar", "X", "baz"],
  ["foo", "A", "bar", "Y", "baz"],
  ["foo", "A", "bar", "Z", "baz"],
  ["foo", "B", "bar", "X", "baz"],
  ["foo", "B", "bar", "Y", "baz"],
  ["foo", "B", "bar", "Z", "baz"],
]
```